# ASP.NET MVC3 - DateTime format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.
My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In view, I have something like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
</div>
```

StartDate is displayed in correct format, but when I change it's value to 19.11.2011 and submit the form, I get the following error message: "The value '19.11.2011' is not valid for StartDate."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to set the proper culture in the globalization element of your web.config file for which `dd.MM.yyyy` is a valid datetime format:

```
<globalization culture="...." uiCulture="...." />
```

For example that's the default format in german: `de-DE`.

---

UPDATE:

According to your requirement in the comments section you want to keep en-US culture of the application but still use a different formats for the dates. This could be achieved by writing a custom model binder:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class MyDateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var displayFormat = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayFormat) && value != null)
        {
            DateTime date;
            displayFormat = displayFormat.Replace("{0:", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);
            // use the format specified in the DisplayFormat attribute to parse the date
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, displayFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                return date;
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                    bindingContext.ModelName, 
                    string.Format("{0} is an invalid date format", value.AttemptedValue)
                );
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

which you will register in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new MyDateTimeModelBinder());
```

Comment: But I wan't use the English culture with different datetime format. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @šljaker, yes there is. You will have to write a custom model binder and manually parse the date parameter using the format you like.

Comment: The globalization Tag is child of the <system.web> Tag.

Comment: hi, Darin, i have a question,`dd/MM/yyyy` format works fine in local machine, but our website hosted in another country, it needs `MM/dd/yyyy` format else it shows validation error `The field BeginDate must be a date.`, how can i make sever to accept `dd/MM/yyyy` format, will globalization work?, can i add globalization in a View page instead of web.config ?

Comment: Can I turn off date validation completely?

Comment: can change at the iis .net globalization setting. change the culture to your corresponding .

Comment: Is it possible to do this for just a single DateTime field? I have one which needs to be formatted specially, while all others should be formatted as usual.

Answer (score 11):

Based upon your comment I see all you want is an english current but with a different date format (Correct me if I'm wrong).

The fact is the `DefaultModelBinder` uses the culture settings of the server for form data. So I can say the server use "en-US" culture but with a different date format.

You can do something like this in the `Application_BeginRequest` and you are done!

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());
    info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<globalization culture="en-US" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this below code to **global.asax.cs** file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()  
{        
    CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());     
    info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;     
}
```

And added the below to **web.config** under `<system.web>`

```
<globalization culture="en-US">;
```