# MVC3 + Datepicker + UK Date

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, date, datepicker

Dudes, been trying for very long time on solving this. I have been looking around and been fiddling around but i just cant get it to work!!

For my DOB, im hoping to accept date in dd/mm/yyyy.. however it only accepts mm/dd/yyyy. Where should i make the fix?

I got inspirations from [Jquery Datepicker 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx) and [Jquery Datepicker 2](http://www.programgood.net/2011/03/19/DatePickerAndMVC3.aspx).

In my Model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

In my View, pretty straight forward

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
```

Have an Editor Template that is called up whenever date is used.

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", Model != null ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") : "", new { @class   = "date" })
```

Wrote another editorhookup, that refs Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should i make the fix?

In your editor template:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "date" })
```

That's for displaying the date in the correct format.

For binding the value back in a POST controller action you could write a [custom model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407) that will use the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to parse the value back to a valid DateTime instance using the specified format.

Comment: all right thanks for the direction man! let me give it a shot!