# jQueryUI DatePicker and MVC4 with UK date value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Ok I know [this question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503663/mvc3-datepicker-uk-date), [and asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427504/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-format-issue-with-initial-value), [and asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138539/jquery-datepicker-will-not-post-with-uk-date-string), but I'm missing something and can't seem to figure it out, cause although the datepicker looks right when I try to submit a date such as 13/04/2013 the validation kicks in and says

> The field [Date Due] must be a date

I've got a date Editor Template

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? 
       Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : 
       string.Empty), new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

ViewModel

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
[DisplayName("Date Due")]
public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
});
```

The datepicker pops up when I enter a field with css class of `datepicker`, I can select a date such as 13th April 2013 in the datepicker, the value shows up in the textbox but on submit fails validation.

Where am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't take any credit for the answer to my problem; but the solution that worked for me was in the [accepted answer for MVC DateTime validation - UK Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14081487/96505) and was

> to overload unobtrusive JavaScript validation method for date

The linked post has script that worked for me as soon as I dropped it into my scripts file.

I'm not sure if this is required because as @Nicholas Butler says

> jQuery Validate doesn't understand cultures.

or if it's because I've used `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: dd MMM yyyy}")]` to make the dates appear as 20 Apr 2013 instead of 20/04/2013 [as pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12109078/96505)

> {0:dd/mm/yyyy} should be {0:dd/MM/yyyy} because mm means minutes, not months:

so could be that the difference between the date formats was causing my problem

Answer (score 0):

Does the following [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1857087.aspx/1?DateTime+DisplayFormat+seems+to+have+no+effect+MVC4+Razor+) help? It implies that the `DisplayFormatAttribute` you've used only kicks in for displaying the date, and doesn't automatically apply to setting the ViewModel property, unless you specify `ApplyFormatInEditMode`. Not great with MVCx, so just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the validation is that jQuery Validate doesn't understand cultures.

For dates, it just calls the javascript: `new Date( value )` which fails for ( some ) UK dates.

So, you need to add globalization to the client-side validator - see my answer to this question:

[DateTime format according to the culture in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044132/datetime-format-according-to-the-culture-in-mvc)