# How can I make the DefaultModelBinder (or another) to understand that 3.000,00 is actually a number?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to find a way to intervene in the way ASP.NET MVC default model binder binds Double values in order to make it to understand that 3.000,00 (or 3,000.00, depending on the culture) is a valid number.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the default model binder understand such numbers. But you could write a [custom model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407) that will use the `DisplayFormat` you defined on the corresponding property.