# DateTime Validation - force to enter time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my C#/MVC4/Razor Application I need to make sure that user enter not only date, but also time. My Model is:

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Start { get; set; }
```

If user enters 02/03/2012, it will be converted to 02/03/2012 00:00.

I tried to implement custom ValidationAttribute, but I receive the value only after it is already converted to DateTime and I don't know, if user entered only date or date with time ("00:00" value).

Is it possible to force user enter date and time?

Comment: perhaps bind to a string instead of datetime and use string for validating and use a datatime wrapper around it for reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom model binder for the DateTime type which will take the `DisplayFormat` attribute format into account when binding the value. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407) such binder.

Comment: Thanks Darin, with this example everything works exactly as I need.