# Issue To fetch date format At Edit() In ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, date-format

When I edit my one of the form sin ASP.NET MVC 3 in this when I edit a user registration form then I got date in startdate is `21-Mar-12 12:00:00 AM` in text box but I need `21-Mar-12`.

So how can I format textbox date like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could decorate the DateTime property on your view model with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute which allows you to specify a given format:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yy}")]
public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
```

and in your strongly typed view use the EditorFor helper to render the corresponding input field:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeDate)
```

As far as binding the value back to a DateTime field when posting back is concerned you could write a custom model binder that will use this format. I have shown an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407).

Comment: Hello Darin thanx for quick reply but when i'm using this synyax then it shows date: "00-21-12" this..

Comment: it works with @Html.TextBox("EndDate", string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", Model.EndDate), new { @class = "EndDate" })