# Format DateTime in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm trying to display a date. Sample of my viewmodel code is below:

```
[Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Enter correct date (e.g. 23.05.1980)")]
public DateTime CustomerBirthday { get; set; }
```

Everything is OK with displaying. But when I want to submit a form, it doesn't pass a validation if first number is greater than 12, because it expects date in format MM.dd.yyyy not dd.MM.yyyy. 
How can I force model binder to use my DateTime pattern (dd.MM.yyyy) and ignore culture settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I force model binder to use my DateTime pattern (dd.MM.yyyy)
>   and ignore culture settings.

You could write a custom model binder that will take into account the format you specified in the DisplayFormat attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407

Answer (score 1):

The `DefaultModelBinder` uses the culture settings of the server for form data. So I can say the server use "en-US" culture but with a different date format.

You can do something like this in the `Application_BeginRequest` and you are done!

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());
    info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
}
```