# Asp.net mvc 4 getting decimal value instead integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, currency

I have a class like:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Value{ get; set; }
}
```

In the form I enter 12.50 and in my post Action the object has Item.Value = 1250 when should have 12.50, How to fix this?

The Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Item item)
{
    ...code...
}
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
</div>
```

When type 12. the validation client side say 'The field Valor must be a number.' however let me execute post action method, with 12, say the same thing but don't let me.

Comment: where's the action method? where's the associated client code?

Comment: just to know, if you try to insert 12,50 (comma) what happens?

Comment: Validation on the client side will not let me. Just let me insert with '.'

Comment: When you look in the database, what is the definition for that column?

Comment: I have tried this code with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and its working fine..  Check if the issue related with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken].

Comment: The definition on the database is money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved with custom bind thanks a Phil Haack (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx). I modified the DecimalModelBind class to:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder 
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
                .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
            object actualValue = null;
            try
            {
                var value = valueResult.AttemptedValue.Replace('.', ',');
                actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value,
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }
            if (bindingContext.ModelState[bindingContext.ModelName] == null)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
            }
            return actualValue;
        }
    }
```

I added these lines:

```
var value = valueResult.AttemptedValue.Replace('.', ',');
if (bindingContext.ModelState[bindingContext.ModelName] == null)
```

The First one to replace ',' by '.' and the second one to check if don't have a ModelState with the same name avoiding exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a Culture on the server that will use `.` as decimal separator such as:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

Alternatively if you want to use `auto` culture (i.e. infer from the client browser settings and the `Accept-Language` request header) then you could write a custom model binder for the decimal type and use the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to explicitly set the desired format. I have illustrated this at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272982/29407 (it's for the DateTime type but you could trivially easy adapt the example for the `decimal` type as well)

Comment: don't work, one more thing I forgot to say when I'm typing '.' on the field the validation client side say 'The field Value must be a number.' but when typing 12.50 he pass and execute post action but 12,50 don't let me execute post action however say the same message 'The field Value must be a number.'