# Formatting DateTime in model to Date only in View

Tags: c#, date, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 5`. I have a date only picker in my create and edit form. In create form, its working just fine. But in edit form, it loads previously saved `DateTime` as `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`. On clicking on textbox, my date picker appears with a calendar of Dec, 1899. Only if I can format my `DateTime`, it will work fine.

Though, I know how to solve this problems in Struts 2, I am new to ASP.NET MVC. Can anybody please tell me how to format my `DateTime` model property to **Date only** in my View?

Here is my model:-

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int VehicleId
    { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vehicle name")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public String Name
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String VehicleType
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Registration no.")]
    public String RegNo
    { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Insurance date")]
    public DateTime InsuranceDate
    { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a part of my view:-

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InsuranceDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-6 input-group date" id="datePick">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InsuranceDate, new { @class = "form-control", id = "datePickText", placeholder = "Enter Insurrance Date" })<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsuranceDate)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You should post your model. Are you using DataAnnotations to format any field? You should post the view code as well.

Comment: I am using bootstrap datepicker

Comment: [DataType(DataType.Date)] Will render the field as type=date. You should take it away.

Comment: What I want is a Date only representation on my view of that `DateTime` object. That's why I applied that attribute. But, I am sure for some very good reasons, it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AsOfdates
{
    public string DisplayDate { get; set; }
    private DateTime TheDate;
    public DateTime DateValue { get { return TheDate.Date; } set { TheDate = value; } }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stablish the format in your property. You can see more information here:

[Format datetime in asp.net mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272851/format-datetime-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` not working on InsuranceDate