# MVC date validation fails with a two digit date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, asp.net-mvc-validation, editorformodel

I'm having a terrible time adding a date to a view.  I want the user to be able to type in a date like 6/30/15 or 6/30/2015, but the validation keeps failing if I use the 2 digit date.  I've tried to "tell" MVC to accept a two digit date, but it always fails.  Can someone explain how to get this right?

My view is set up like this (including just the troublesome date field for brevity):

```
@model Models.CompanyContracts
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BegDate)
```

I started out with a simple model with a date field defined like this:

```
public DateTime? BegDate { get; set; }
```

I got an error saying "The field BegDate must be a date" when I entered the date as 6/30/15 or 06/30/15; I did not get the error when I entered 6/30/2015 or 06/30/2015.

So I tried to add a type and display attribute as describe
Here: [Format datetime in asp.net mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272851/format-datetime-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:M/d/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

I get the same error trying to enter 6/30/15.  I tried several different formats, including a datatype and not a displayformat, including a displayformat and not a datatype, but I get the "The field BegDate must be a date" error everytime.

I tried a regular expression validation and it also failed (both the MVC validation and the regular expression; obviously the regex I got from http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 needs some work):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
    public DateTime? BegDate { get; set; }
```

Can someone tell me how to get MVC to accept entering dates with 2 or 4 digits?

One other note, no external date pickers.  I need to get this working with a simple entering of text.  Once I can prove that can be done, my boss might allow me to spend some time figuring out a date picker.  Thanks!

-- Update 7/20/15 --
Anyone have suggestions for this?  I haven't found anything online that's helped me.  I'd appreciate any feedback at this point to give me somewhere else to look for a solution.

-- Update 7/29/15 --
Still looking for suggestions.  Any ideas at all?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this at all. Entering a date with 2 digits for the year works fine. Is the form actually submitting and hitting the POST method (i.e. is client side validation generating the error or is model binding generating the error)? Possibly your server culture is set to a culture that expect the date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` meaning that `6/30/15` would be invalid (it would need to be `30/6/15`)

Comment: It's never getting to a post method.  The error "The field BegDate must be a date" appears on the screen whenever I enter a two digit date.  I don't click on the save (post) button yet.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply not possible without some kind of twist. 
How is the engine/code suppose to know which year it is if you enter just 15 as the year.
Is it 2015 ? 1915 ? 2115 ? 
You need to pass the 4 digits to create the dates, if you only have 2 digits you cannot create the date. 
So in your case what I would try is to default and hide the '20' prefix (assuming you can only enter a date for 2000's) to your 2 digits year input (or add it somehow using a bit a javascript).