# date format dd/MM/yyyy not working in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, date-formatting

I'm developing an asp.net mvc 5 application, in which I'm trying to set a validation for **dd/MM/yyyy** format, I've been struggling a lot to find an appropriate solution but no success, what I want it to accept:

`24/01/2016`

but it displays validation message as :

> The field JoiningDate must be a date.

Here is what I've tried :

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
```

Also, I want it to display the date in **dd/MM/yyyy** format everywhere at the user's end but this is a second part of my question, firstly, it should at least allow a valid date input. I'm stuck on this one, any help will be **deeply** appreciated, I've searched all over, but I'm not being able to get to the point, Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Try using a datatype: [DataType(DataType.Date)]

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Assuming your server culture is one that accepts dates in `dd/MM/yyyy`, then the issue is `jquery.validate` which validates dates in the `MM/dd/yyyy` format. You have not indicated if your using a datepicker, but refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) for some options

Comment: @StephenMuecke , I tried `jquery.validate` but no success, and Now, it is displaying jQuery validation message `The value '24/01/2015' is not valid for Joining Date.` , I've been struggling on this for 2 days, and I badly need you :(

Comment: If your using client side validation, then you need to configure the validator (e.g. using jquery.globalize,js) as per the link. If you were not previously using client side validation, then the error suggests the culture on the server was one that did not accept dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format (so change it, or use a custom `ModelBinder`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke , I used Custom ModelBinder, and the issue is resolved, Thank You so much for giving me such awesome idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer, I used custom ModelBinder, in order to resolve this issue,

Firstly, I registered this line in the application_start method in Global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new MyDateTimeModelBinder());
```

Here is the custom ModelBinder :

```
public class MyDateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var displayFormat = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayFormat) && value != null)
        {
            DateTime date;
            displayFormat = displayFormat.Replace("{0:", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);
            // use the format specified in the DisplayFormat attribute to parse the date
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, displayFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                return date;
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                    bindingContext.ModelName,
                    string.Format("{0} is an invalid date format", value.AttemptedValue)
                );
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Thanks to Darin Dimitrov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272982/5180893)!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way, I found was put in the web.config the code below

```
 <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is much cleaner solution i figured out.

Client validation issues can occur because of MVC bug (even in MVC 5) in *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js* which **does not accept date/datetime format in any way**. Unfortunately you have to solve it manually.

**My finally working solution:**

You have to include before:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.js")
```

You can install moment.js using:

```
Install-Package Moment.js
```

And then you can finally add fix for date format parser:

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD.MM.YYYY", true).isValid();
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!. Don't forget to register moment.js in the BundleConfig.cs or it will not render.