# ASP.NET MVC : DateTime is taking format as MM/dd/yyyy but I need in dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
public class Employee
{
       [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateOfRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

My .cshtml:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfRegistration, 
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" } })
```

jQuery code:

```
$('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
```

Please help me - how can I get date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: kindly check out this https://jsfiddle.net/m7fe3Lyx/4/

Comment: I exactly had the same issues few years back, take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35992327/5180893)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      $("#format").on("change", function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>

  <p>Format options:<br>
    <select id="format">
      <option value="dd-mm-yy">dd-mm-yy</option>
      <option value="dd/mm/yy">dd/mm/yy</option>
    </select>
  </p>


</body>

</html>
```

for more help kindly refer [Change Date Format of jQuery Datepicker to dd/mm/yy](https://www.encodedna.com/jquery/ui-datepicker-widget-change-date-format.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Change your dateFormat from this: `dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",`

to this: `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`

More info [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) and [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

Hope this helps

Comment: no Use same issue Bro