# Datetime editortemplate not applied in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I searched almost every topic on this site regarding date format also DatePicker however couldn't find any solution for my issue, also applied [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272851/format-datetime-in-asp-net-mvc-4)
with no success

**Problems**

1. Date format is not applied in Partial views
2. datepicker is not applied in Partial views

**.cs**

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? RefDate{ get; set; }
```

**Razor (Partial View)**

In my main view, when Edit is clicked, i load a partial view inside a div, the partial view contains:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RefDate, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
```

**DateTime.cshtml**

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") :string.Empty),
new { @class = "datepicker" ,@readonly = "readonly"})
```

**Web.Config**

```
<globalization culture='fr-BE' uiCulture='fr-BE' />
```

**Result**

> 02/18/2015 0:00:00

IF i use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RefDate, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
```

**Result**
I don't see any value but this text:

> mm/dd/yyyy

Also bootstsrap format is gone.

Comment: `TextBoxFor()` will not use your `EditorTempate` (`DateTime.cshtml`). To use `TextBoxFor()` with a format, it needs to be `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RefDate, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })`

Comment: `EditorFor()` will call your template (although its unclear what the point of that template is - its should be just `@Html.TextBox("", new { @class = "datepicker" ,@readonly = "readonly"})` but it sounds like you might be  generating the browsers HTML5 datepicker (does the html have `type="date"`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your DateTime.cshtml template file is not correctly located, it should be in a folder named "EditorTempaltes" in the "Shared" view folder, or in your current view folder, like that :

[image]

Or like that :

[image]

And use Html.EditorFor to call your template.

### Edit :

Try to decorate your property with the UiHintAttribute to indicate that you model use the DateTime.cshtml template file :

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[UIHint("DateTime")]
public DateTime? RefDate{ get; set; }
```

Comment: My DateTime.cshtml is correctly located. also it works with normal view but not partial view.