# Specify Date format in MVC5 (dd/MM/yyyy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I'm trying to handle user input for date values, I want to prompt user to input date in this format: dd/MM/yyyy

**what I tried to do:**

I read and implement the answer for Darin in this question:
[Format datetime in asp.net mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272851/format-datetime-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

This is my implementation:

In Global.asax

```
    (ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var displayFormat = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayFormat) && value != null)
        {
            DateTime date;
            displayFormat = displayFormat.Replace
            ("{0:", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                return date;
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                    bindingContext.ModelName,
                    string.Format("{0} is an invalid date format", value.AttemptedValue)
                );
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
```

Departure Date in Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Departure date is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Departure Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
```

In view:

```
 <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DesignVacation.DepartureDate)
                            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DesignVacation.DepartureDate)

                        </div>
```

And this is the output when run the view:
[image]

It starts with month(mm) but what I want is this format:
dd/MM/yyyy

How to get this format using editorFor(and if possible with textboxFor).

Answer (score 9):

You're generating the browser's HTML5 datepicker by using `EditorFor()` in conjunction with the `[DataType]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes. The specifications require that the format be `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format). Change the attribute to:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Departure date is required")]
[Display(Name = "Departure Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
```

and the date will be displayed in the culture of the user's device, which is what the HTML-5 datepicker is for.

Note that you do not need a custom model binder (the date will be posted in ISO format and will be correctly bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`).

Note however that the HTML-5 datepicker is only supported in Chrome and Edge, and a normal textbox will be displayed in Firefox (for example). If you want a consistent UI, then it is recommended you use a jquery datepicker plugin (e.g. jquery-UI) but you will also need to reconfigure the validator for client side validation (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) for an example).

Answer (score 3):

if you look at documentation of [DisplayFormatAttribute.DataFormatString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see

> Gets or sets the display format for the field value.

it is not mentioned that it will change the design format of the `datepicker`, it only chages the format of the value. since you are getting date from `HTML 5 date picker` you cannot change its format [Is there any way to change input type=“date” format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) 
 and also some browsers does not support `HTML 5 date picker` but you can use `jquery date picker`

add this in `head`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and in `body`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DesignVacation.DepartureDate)
```

and finally add `script`

```
<script>

   $(function(){

       $('#DesignVacation_DepartureDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });

});

</script>
```