# Why is globalization date format not working in Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config

I thought that I had the correct settings in my web config file to ensure that all of my users see British dates formats, when accessing my Web App hosted through Azure. However I have a client in a different country that sees a different date format.

```
<system.web>  
   <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
</system.web>
```

Does anyone know if I'm missing any other settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you globally set the date format in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300841/how-do-you-globally-set-the-date-format-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Adding **`WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`** with the value **`W. Europe Standard Time`** doesn't change the culture it only affects the time zone.

Any setting either by web.config or from Azure Web App setting doesn't have any impact on it, No matter what Azure runs on UTC, for changing the culture you need to write extra code to make change in the datetime.

You can check this thread for reference:

[Why are the dates in my MVC app in the wrong format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083811/why-are-the-dates-in-my-mvc-app-in-the-wrong-format)

Also as suggested by **`hujtomi`**, check the link shared .

Hope it helps.