# ASP.NET MVC 5 DataFormatString for date is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Tried various solutions out there related to `DataFormatString` but nothing is working for me for following piece of code (Date Format `dd-MM-yyyy` not applying in html Form)

```
 [Column("dateOfBirth")]
 [Required]
 [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
 [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
 public virtual DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

and Inside the html

```
 <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is happening? Are you trying to display the browsers HTML-5 datapicker?

Comment: date picker is showing properly but the format is mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: Its needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format). The whole point of the HTML-5 datepicker is to render the date in the culture of the users browser.

Comment: Refer also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820926/specify-date-format-in-mvc5-dd-mm-yyyy/43826746#43826746)

Comment: Can we override this behavior ? I mean It's my App requirement to show in dd-MM-yyyy format.

Comment: Then use a jquery datepicker (you cannot control the users browser)

Comment: OK. from end user point of view If user wants the date time picker to use dd-MM-yyyy format. Then how he/she can set it ? I mean where in Chrome user can set this format ?

Comment: Also if I as developer digest this behavior but want to store dd-MM-yyyy in db then what changes need to be done before `                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges(); `

Comment: try adding `value` inside `EditorFor` like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" ,@Value=Model.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString()} })`

Comment: You cannot change it (you have no control over how the browser renders its HTML-5 date picker). Again, use a jquery datepicker (e.g. [jquery-ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) which will give you full control.