# The Date format in Html.EditorFor not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC project, but there's a problem in using Date Format.

Here is my code:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> docDate { get; set; }
```

and in the HTML side

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.docDate)
```

and I do not know where is the problem the format always came like this "MM/dd/yyyy"

please help me in this issue.

Comment: I try to use this but it came alse "MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: @Zozo - Look at the following post: [Specify Date format in MVC5 (dd/MM/yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43820926/6630084). The `DisplayFormat` is intended for **displaying** and has no effect on the `datepicker` control.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify Date format in MVC5 (dd/MM/yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820926/specify-date-format-in-mvc5-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Maybe, using jquery is also an option. `$(function () {
 $("#docDate").datepicker();
 $("#docDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy');
});`