# How to change the default "The field must be a number"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an MVC 3 application. One of the fields in the model is of type double and defined as follows:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ListingItemPriceRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages))]
    [Display(Name = "DisplayListingItemPrice", ResourceType = typeof(Display))]
    [Range(1, 500000000, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ListingItemPriceNotWithinRange", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages))]
    public double Price { get; set; }
```

Still, when I enter a value of a number with some trailing spaces like "342   ", I get the default message "The field price must be a number".

Even the validation attribute on the Price input field has something as "data-val-number".

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default message is baked deeply into the framework, as a string resource. It is added by the default model binder when trying to bind the string value to a double type. So if you want to change this default message you could write a custom model binder. Here's an example I wrote for the DateTime type which has the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407

Comment: Thanks Darin. For each data type there is a model binder? btw, do you have a blog?

Comment: I implemented a custom model binder, but still on the client side, the same sentence is displayed, the default one. How to inject another message even on client side? Thanks

Answer (score 18):

If you're ok with changing just the unobtrusive validation side of things, you can always supply your own jquery validation attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "data-val-number", "Price must be a valid number." } })
```

Or, the following is simpler as MVC replaces underscores with dashes in attribute names:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { data_val_number = "Price must be a valid number." })
```

Comment: Awesome solution @ScottE, literally I was searched the whole internet but didn't find any relavent solution. This works great. Thank you...!!!!!

Comment: Wow! I'm also surprised this worked so easily! Thanks Scott!

Comment: Perfect answer !!

Answer (score 6):

I found it easier to just say:

```
 [RegularExpression("([0-9]+)", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessage), ErrorMessageResourceName = "NumberInvalid")]
```

Comment: This is a much simpler way of doing it.