# How to display two different error message in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I want to display two different error message. First give for required and second for Int64   value. Here is my code.

```
    [Display(Name = "Employee")]
    [Required]
    public Int64 EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

Comment: What does 'second for int64 value' mean?

Comment: 'second for int64 value' mean : by default if i give string  value in text  box. That case it give error message 'The field must be a number'. But i want to display other message.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to change the default “The field must be a number”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831721/how-to-change-the-default-the-field-must-be-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data annotation extentions here: http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

Then add the two annotations as follows:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Id is required")]
[DataAnnotationsExtensions.Integer(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid number.")]
public Int64 EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RangeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx).

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Msg1")]
[Range(10, 1000, 
    ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public object Weight;
```