# Data binding MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding

I have no idea what am i doing wrong.
Well i have this form, it's part of complex view.

```
    @{
    var filtersAjaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "clientList-body",
            OnBegin = "clientList.filterRequestStart()",
            OnComplete = "clientList.filterRequestComplete()",
            OnSuccess = "clientList.filterRequestSuccess()"
        };
    }
    <span class="clientFilters-filterValue inlineBlock">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
            "Index",
            "ClientList",
            new {
                ProductId = Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.ProductId,
                ClientFilter = Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.ClientFilter,
                BillFilter = Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.BillFilter,
                DateSortType = Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.DateSortType,
                SortDirection = Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.SortDirection
            },
            filtersAjaxOptions,
            new
            {
                id = "clientListDateFilter-form"
            }
        ))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(
                m => m.ClientListViewModel.Filters.BeginDateRange,
                new
                {
                    @class = "dp-input textInput inlineBlock",
                    id = "dp-billDateFilterStart",
                }
            )
            @Html.TextBoxFor(
                m => m.ClientListViewModel.Filters.EndDateRange,
                new
                {
                    @class = "dp-input textInput inlineBlock",
                    id = "dp-billDateFilterEnd",
                }
            )
        }
    </span>
```

Here's the filters model

```
    public class FilterModel
    {
        public FilterModel()
        {
            ClientFilter = ClientsEnum.All;
            BillFilter = ClientBillsEnum.All;
        }

        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public ClientsEnum ClientFilter { get; set; }
        public ClientBillsEnum BillFilter { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BeginDateRange { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDateRange { get; set; }
        public DateSortType? DateSortType { get; set; }
        public SortDirection? SortDirection { get; set; }
    }
```

This part is **ClientListController** method **Index**:

```
    public ActionResult Index(FilterModel filters)
    {
        var clientListViewModel = GetClientListViewModel(filters, 1, 1, PageSize);
        if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("Partial/ClientListBody", clientListViewModel);
        return View(clientListViewModel);
    }
```

Whenever i submit the form above, it turns to me that fields "BeginDateRange" and "EndDateRange" are null and other fields are set properly. Although, when i insert **Request.Form** in Watch, i can see the whole data.

**UPDATE 1**
So i set the <globalisation> in Web.config as this:

```
    <globalisation responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US">
```

and yet it doesn't work. Very same result as before.

**UPDATE 2**
Also when i tried to put all the routevalues data into @Html.HiddenFor, controller saw only nulls. And again, Request.Form is filled prprly.

So the question is: how can i bind form data to incoming model?
TY

Comment: Can you post your `filtersAjaxOptions`? What culture do you use? Can you post a sample date?

Comment: filterAjaxOptions are okay, but ok, ill post

Comment: I use default MVC3 culture, which is, i believe "en-US"?

Comment: So sample date is like 03.22.2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The default model binder uses the current culture datetime format when binding datetimes. This means that you have to enter the date into the proper format in your textboxes. On the other hand if you need a fixed format you could use a fixed culture in your web.config (`<globalization>` element) or write a custom model binder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407</strike>

---

UPDATE:

You need to specify the correct binding prefix because your input fields are named like `ClientListViewModel.Filters.BeginDateRange` but your controller action takes a `FilterModel` as parameter instead of the root view model:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "ClientListViewModel.Filters")] FilterModel filters)
{
    ...
}
```

But now this will break the other values, so you need to adjust your view as well:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Index",
    "ClientList",
    null,
    filtersAjaxOptions,
    new
    {
        id = "clientListDateFilter-form"
    }
 ))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClientListViewModel.Filters.ProductId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClientListViewModel.Filters.ClientFilter)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClientListViewModel.Filters.BillFilter)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClientListViewModel.Filters.DateSortType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClientListViewModel.Filters.SortDirection)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        m => m.ClientListViewModel.Filters.BeginDateRange,
        new
        {
            @class = "dp-input textInput inlineBlock",
            id = "dp-billDateFilterStart",
        }
    )
    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        m => m.ClientListViewModel.Filters.EndDateRange,
        new
        {
            @class = "dp-input textInput inlineBlock",
            id = "dp-billDateFilterEnd",
        }
    )
}
```

or if you want to send them as part of the form url instead if using hidden fields:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "Index",
    "ClientList",
    new RouteValueDictionary 
    { 
        { "ClientListViewModel.Filters.ProductId", Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.ProductId },
        { "ClientListViewModel.Filters.ClientFilter", Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.ClientFilter },
        { "ClientListViewModel.Filters.BillFilter", Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.BillFilter },
        { "ClientListViewModel.Filters.DateSortType", Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.DateSortType },
        { "ClientListViewModel.Filters.SortDirection", Model.ClientListViewModel.Filters.SortDirection },
    },
    filtersAjaxOptions,
    new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        { "id", "clientListDateFilter-form" }
    }
 ))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        m => m.ClientListViewModel.Filters.BeginDateRange,
        new
        {
            @class = "dp-input textInput inlineBlock",
            id = "dp-billDateFilterStart",
        }
    )
    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        m => m.ClientListViewModel.Filters.EndDateRange,
        new
        {
            @class = "dp-input textInput inlineBlock",
            id = "dp-billDateFilterEnd",
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample data for this field?

Comment: 01/01/2012 as en-US. I also tried 01.01.2012 with ru-RU culture. Still didn't work

Comment: How about `2012-01-01` with en-US in your web.config?

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) says en-US short date format is dd/MM/yyyy? Or i don't get the whole concept

Comment: Empty string. I'm depressed =\

Comment: @VladislavQulin, sorry, only now I understood what the problem is; Please checkout my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Index(FilterModel filters, FormCollection collection)
{
    UpdateModel(filters, "ClientListViewModel");
    var clientListViewModel = GetClientListViewModel(filters, 1, 1, PageSize);
    if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("Partial/ClientListBody", clientListViewModel);
    return View(clientListViewModel);
}
```

And in view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
            m => m.ClientListViewModel.FilterModel.EndDateRange,
            new
            {
                @class = "dp-input textInput inlineBlock",
                id = "dp-billDateFilterEnd",
            }
        )
```

You have strange naming. Also it would be better to use hidden fields then passing values through routevalues.

Comment: >> Also it would be better to use hidden fields then passing values through routevalues. - why?

Comment: m => m.ClientListViewModel.Filters.EndDateRange you have ClientListViewModel and Filters. It would be better -> ClientListViewModel.FilterModel

Comment: Well that sounds legit. And what about hidden fields and routevalues?

Comment: You will be able to manipulate with hidden fields easily. It's only my concern about hidden fields vs routevalues

Comment: This form only have responsibility to operate with date ranges. So routevalues in this case are some sort of incapsulation principle)

Comment: @VladislavQulin can you show me how Request.Form is filled (or formcollection names)? Binding depends on that names. Then i will surely help you