# How to Format nullable decimal as currency in mvc 3 razor view for display purpose only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need help to format nullable decimal field as currency (with dollar sign and commas) in mvc application's razor view. Below is my modal and view code.

**Model**:

```
[Display(Name = "Eligible Amount")]
[RequiredIfProjectEngineerSelected("ProjectEngineerId", "", ErrorMessage = "Eligible Amount field is Required")]        
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]        
public decimal? EligibleAmount { get; set; }
```

**View**:

```
@{var formated = String.Format("{0:c}",  decimal)decimal.Parse(@Model.project.ProjectTotalCost.HasValue ? @Model.project.ProjectTotalCost.Value.ToString() : ""));}
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.project.ProjectTotalCost, new { @Value = formatted})
```

It is displaying the formatted currency value in TextBoxFor control. But the problem what I am facing here is, when I am trying to update the value back, getting validation error saying "the value is not matching format".

Comment: if you are talking about the display format, you need `@model.EligibleAmount .ToString("c")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions given to me on this. I am able to solve this problem by using the ModelBinder.

As Per [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235103/712526), I cannot change the control from TextBoxFor to EditorFor as I need apply styles on that. ModelBinder works with TextBoxFor control also.

~ Balaji

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Do you still have the code for this? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First things first, you should replace the 2 lines of code you have shown in your view with a single line of code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.EligibleAmount)
```

which will take into account the `DisplayFormat` attribute you defined on your model and you don't need to repeat this format in the view. You just need to enable it in edit mode by setting the `ApplyFormatInEditMode` property to `true`:

```
[Display(Name = "Eligible Amount")]
[RequiredIfProjectEngineerSelected("ProjectEngineerId", "", ErrorMessage = "Eligible Amount field is Required")]        
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]        
public decimal? EligibleAmount { get; set; }
```

Alright, this solves the displaying part. But the model binding part is still an issue. For that you could write a custom model binder which will take into account the format defined in your `DisplayFormat` attribute. I have shown an example of such a model binder with DateTime at [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407). All you have to do is adapt it for the `decimal` time which should be a trivial task.

Comment: Thanks Drain for helping me out. I cannot change the the control from TextBoxFor to EditorFor as I need to apply styles.

Comment: @Darin Wouldn't that work differently for a `decimal` versus a `Nullable<decimal>`?