# How to validate date in my model at client side with data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have 2 specific require for date validation. 
1) date field should be mandatory
2) invalid date will not be accepted.

when date will be empty then i want to show "Date is required"

when date will be invalid then i want to show "Date is invalid"

so guide me how could i do this.

here i try to wrote a code but do not know does it work or not.

```
public class Student
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "DOB require")]
        [Display(Name = "DOB :")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }

    }
```

help me to implement this at client side. thanks

### EDIT

one person guide me in this way
Inorder to validate date format, its better to create a custom ValidationAttribute as shown below

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false,
    AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DateOnlyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DateOnlyAttribute() :
        base("\"{0}\" must be a date without time portion.")
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)value;
                return dateTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
            else if (value.GetType() == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>))
            {
                DateTime? dateTime = (DateTime?)value;
                return !dateTime.HasValue
                    || dateTime.Value.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            ErrorMessageString, name);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it as data annotation as shown below

```
  [DateOnly]
public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
```

### but the above code is not clear to me because i am new in MVC

here is few question on the above code

this code is not clear

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)value;
                return dateTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
            else if (value.GetType() == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>))
            {
                DateTime? dateTime = (DateTime?)value;
                return !dateTime.HasValue
                    || dateTime.Value.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

1) when this is true then what will be return

if (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))

2) what this line will do

return dateTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;

3) what is the meaning of this line

else if (value.GetType() == typeof(Nullable))

4) what is the meaning of this below code

```
DateTime? dateTime = (DateTime?)value;
                return !dateTime.HasValue
                    || dateTime.Value.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;
```

please guide me in detail to understand the code what u have written. thanks

Comment: You could write a custom model binder to handle this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7836093/29407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the following code in the .cshtml file in which you need the client side validation,

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**EDIT**

The explanation for the last 4 questions you have asked,

1) `if (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))` Checks the type of 'value'(object) can be DateTime or not ! In other word, it checks for non nullable date format.

2) `return dateTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;` returns false if 'value' has a valid date
TimeSpan.Zero returns TimeSpan for Zero Time (00:00:00) 
Note: if you cannot cast 'value' to date time, you get 'datetime' value equal to TimeSpan.Zero

3) `else if (value.GetType() == typeof(Nullable)<DateTime>)` Same case a question 1, but checking for nullable DateTime (Note: Nullable DateTime and non nullable DateTime are treated as different datatype)

4)

```
    DateTime? dateTime = (DateTime?)value;
    return !dateTime.HasValue || dateTime.Value.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Same case as question 2, if you cannot cast to nullable DateTime, you have 'datetime' equal to TimeSpan.Zero

Comment: probably u did not understand what is my requirement. i want to validate date at client side using data annotation. i am familiar with data annotation. i want that when date field will empty then a message will say "Date Required" and when user enter invalid date then a message will display "Invalid date" at client side. here u try to guide how to use data annotation that is not my question.

Comment: make sure you ask your question clearly. you have mentioned "here i try to wrote a code but do not know does it work or not." and that's the reason i gave previous solution. Check for my updated answer