# validating date format not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, globalization

I'm having problem with date validation. In my View, I have a jQuery datepicker - I changed the format from `yy/mm/dd` to `mm/dd/yy` and now I get client-side validation errors. For example,

```
    The value '02/25/2014' is not valid for Date of Birth.
```

The Javascript:

```
$('#DateOfBirth').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    yearRange: "-90:-5"
});
```

The View Model:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

The View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.DateOfBirth, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I overlooked something. The validation actually fails on the server side. So this has nothing to do with jQuery. The `ModelState.IsValid == false` for me.

Comment: You have MM/dd/yyyy in your view, but mm/dd/yy in your JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery takes `mm` and .NET `MM` for numeric months.

Comment: But `yy` is not the same as `yyyy`.

Comment: For some reason jQuery datepicker uses `yy` for 4-digit year. Using `yyyy` gives something like `20142014`.

Comment: Ok. For basic JavaScript, `yyyy` is 2014 and `yy` is 14.

Comment: You should make the answer in your question a real **Answer** and accept it. But use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.DateOfBirth, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })` - don't attempt to override the model binding features of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: [ASP.NET MVC3 - DateTime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835614/asp-net-mvc3-datetime-format)
and it had to do with globalization.

My locale is `en-CA` and

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

gives `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

So in `Web.config` under `<system.web>` I included

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>
```

So the DateTime format is working for me now.

**P.S.**

A safe way to pass dates without worrying about specific culture is to use ISO 8601 format - `yyyy-MM-dd` (or `yyyy/MM/dd` which also works).