# date format error in mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

when i click button client side date format is working fine but server side date format is different

how to solve this problem?

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckAvailabilityValue(MainModel check)
        {

            try
            {
                Get_Location();
                //if (ModelState.IsValid)
                //{
                    locationInformation checking = new locationInformation();
                    bool suc = checking.CheckAvailability(check);
                    if (suc == false)
                    {
                        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Checked successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else if (suc == true)
                    {
                        return Json(new { False = true, message = "Checked successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                //}
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

MainModel Class:

```
public class CheckingDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookingID { get; set; }
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        public int FacilityID { get; set; }
        public int VenueID { get; set; }
        public int CapacityID { get; set; }
        public DateTime BookedFromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime BookedToDate { get; set; }
        public string FromTime { get; set; }
        public string ToTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Below i attached screen shot

[image: Screen2]

[image: Screen1]

[image: sereen3]

```
public bool CheckAvailability(MainModel check)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["venue"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckAvailability", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookedFromDate", Convert.ToDateTime(check.CheckMasters.BookedFromDate));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookedToDate", Convert.ToDateTime(check.CheckMasters.BookedToDate));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromTime", check.CheckMasters.FromTime);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToTime", check.CheckMasters.ToTime);
                con.Open();
                flag = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                return flag;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Could be the format. Have you tried month/day/year ?

Comment: no sir@ric .....

Comment: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.  @ric

Comment: in client side or server side? @IswarKChettri

Comment: When you changed the format did you see the correct value in the debugger?

Comment: How are you checking the date value in your server side?

Comment: data value is different@IswarKChettri

Comment: see my screen shot @IswarKChettri

Comment: have you tried ` date.toISOString() ` in your client before passing the date value to server?

Comment: The value "1/1/0001 12:00:00AM" is the default for a DateTime, so for some reason the values are not even arriving on the server side.

Comment: yes correct  how to solve  this issue

Comment: what is your client environment?

Comment: need to pass date

Comment: Some unrelated tips: `SqlCommand` is `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block. You may want to take a look at [Can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Also your error message indicates that you're using DateTime as the Sql column type, you may want to consider using DateTime2 (it won't solve your problem), or since those fields are just dates use the Date type.

Comment: @IvinRaj consider editing the question to make the question clearer, rather than adding to the clutter of these comments. E.g. The question says server side format is different, but that isn't the problem, the problem is that it isn't arriving.

Comment: It is possible to be a format issue. You can use Data Annotation in model like [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]. For more solution check this question thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835614/asp-net-mvc3-datetime-format/7836093#7836093

Comment: The format that you send to the controller must match your server culture. If you want to send dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` as your doing then you must change the culture of your server to one that accepts dates in that format (and just use `$('form').serialize()` rather than that unnecessary `GetInfo()` function)

Comment: Just to confirm this is a culture issue - do a test and post back some dates where the day is less that or equal to 12 - e.g. 4/6/2018 and 10/6/2018 and confirm its saving (but it will save it as 6th April and 6th October)

Comment: What do you mean not working? And what is the culture on your server?

Comment: @StephenMuecke what is the culture on your server means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173666/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ivin-raj).